# In C# how does one call a static method using emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am trying to using Emit to generate mapping code (mapping properties from one object to another).  I have it working if the two types match (source and target), but I can't get it to work in an instance where the types don't match and I need to call a static method in the mapping.  Below is code that I thought would work but I get a method does not exist error even though it does.  I am guessing my emit call is incorrect.  Any suggestions?

```
foreach (var map in maps)
{
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

  il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, map.SourceProperty.GetGetMethod(), null);
  if (map.SourceProperty.PropertyType == map.TargetProperty.PropertyType)
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, map.TargetProperty.GetSetMethod(), null);
  else if (map.TargetProperty.PropertyType.Name == "ObjectId" && map.SourceProperty.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "string") {
    var method = typeof(ObjectId).GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, Type.DefaultBinder,  new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, method , null);
  }

}
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call it by using `EmitCall` with [`OpCodes.Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx) instead of `CallVirt`.

Comment: I had tried that and I got JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation so I figured I was going down the wrong path.  The ILCode looks like :     IL_0006:  call       valuetype [MongoDB.Bson]MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId [MongoDB.Bson]MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId::Parse(string)
    IL_000b:  stfld      valuetype [MongoDB.Bson]MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId ClassLibrary1.Class1::obj but I am a noob to Emit so not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Actually, you got me 50% there.  The CallVirt was incorrect and then I had to follow that up with the following line:                     il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method , null);
                    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, map.TargetProperty.GetSetMethod(), null);

Answer (score -1):

This is the line that's throwing the error?

```
var method = typeof(ObjectId).GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, Type.DefaultBinder,  new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
```

Perhaps you could try

```
Type ObjectIDType = typeof(ObjectId);
MethodInfo method = ObjectIDType.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
```

Perhaps parse takes an object as its parameter instead of a string?

What is the error message?